# splitting multiple delimiters into a table

Tags: postgresql, split

I need to put the below grep output into a postgresql table. I am unsure how to do this.

log.txt:

```
2023-03-01 00:40:26 , "rami"."big_white_shoes"
2023-03-01 13:10:42 , black_shoes
-bash-4.2$
```

table created as:

```
postgres=# CREATE TABLE ddl_log (ts timestamp, user text, table varchar2);
postgres=# \copy ddl_log FROM 'log.tx' WITH DELIMITER [??]
```

expected table to have:

| timestamp | user | table |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-01 00:40:26 | rami | big_white_shoes |
| 2023-03-01 13:10:42 |  | black_shoes |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your log have (or not have) user as part of your second column. To achieve the desired result, you would use a temporary table. ie:

```
CREATE TABLE ddl_log (ts timestamp, "user" text, "table" text);
create temporary table mylog (logDate timestamp, data text);
copy mylog from 'c:\myFolder\log.txt' delimiter ',';
insert into ddl_log (ts, "user", "table")
select logdate, case when data like '%"."%' then left(data, position('.' in data)-1 ) end,
       case when data like '%"."%' then substring(data from position('.' in data)+1) else data end
     from mylog;
drop table if exists mylog;
select * from ddl_log;
drop table if exists ddl_log;
```